# how to call value of the <select> in php code

Tags: php, mysql

guys i am confuse why is it i still getting this error..

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\se\addstock.php on line 93"..`

as you know i am new in php that's why i can't catch this simple error.. 
here it is, i have this code

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user     = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "dbms2";
$bd             = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT prodcode from purchasings");
?>
<tr>
<td width="91">Product Code </td>
<td width="149">
    <select name="choice">
        <?php while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
            echo '<option >'.$data['prodcode'];
            echo '</option>';
            } 
        ?>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
<?php $results = mysql_query("select * from purchasings where prodcode = '"$_POST['choice']"'");
    $datas = mysql_fetch_array ($results); ?> 
    <tr><td>Product Name </td><td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $datas['prodname'];
?>"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Category </td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Date </td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
```

as you know my select is named as "choice" and it's value or it's options is from my database. i tried to use the $_post and $_get but still there is an error.. can you please help me how to do it??

Comment: your `$_POST['choice']` is not defined. check your code to form submit throught `get` or `post`

Comment: Loop up string concatenation. And next a recent tutorial on database queries and bound parameters etc.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the [concatenation operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) in this line:

```
mysql_query("select * from purchasings where prodcode = '"$_POST['choice']"'")
```

It should be:

```
mysql_query("select * from purchasings where prodcode = '" . $_POST['choice'] . "'")
// --------------------------------------------------------^------------------^
```

Also, it's worth adding that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Please use either [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

Comment: now i have this error Notice: Undefined index: choice in C:\xampp\htdocs\se\addstock.php on line 93... and it does not posting the data from mysql database... by the way how can i define it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit through form to access value from $_POST array

Please try following code

code edited

```
    <?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user     = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "dbms2";
$bd             = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT prodcode from purchasings");
?>
<tr>
<td width="91">Product Code </td>
<td width="149">
    <form method="post"><select onchange="javascript:document,forms[0].submit()" name="choice">
        <?php 
        $firstValue="";
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
            if($firstValue==""){ $firstValue=$data['prodcode']; }
            if(isset($_POST["choice"]) and trim($_POST["choice"])==$data['prodcode']){
                echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$data['prodcode'].'" >'.$data['prodcode'];
                echo '</option>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<option value="'.$data['prodcode'].'" >'.$data['prodcode'];
                echo '</option>';
            }
            } 
        ?>
    </select></form>
</td>
</tr>
<?php if(isset($_POST["choice"])){
    $results = mysql_query("select * from purchasings where prodcode = '".$_POST['choice']."'");
}else{
    $results = mysql_query("select * from purchasings where prodcode = '".$firstValue."'");
}
    $datas = mysql_fetch_array ($results); ?> 
    <tr><td>Product Name </td><td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $datas['prodname'];
?>"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Category </td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Date </td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
```

Comment: Put your select box inside the form  and you must put value property inside the option tag to get the value through post array  `<form action="" method="post"><select name="choice">
        <?php while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$data['prodcode'].'" >'.$data['prodcode'];
            echo '</option>';
            } 
        ?>
    </select></form>`

Comment: And insert a submit button inside form.If you want to submit the form on change, add the following javascript on onchange event `<select name="choice" onchange="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();"> `

Comment: and change the code like following `<?php
if(isset($_POST["choice"])){
 $results = mysql_query("select * from purchasings where prodcode = '".$_POST['choice']."'");
    $datas = mysql_fetch_array ($results); ?> 
    <tr><td>Product Name </td><td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $datas['prodname'];
?>"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Category </td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Date </td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
 
<?php
}
?>`

Comment: sorry guys for bothering you, why is it not working maybe because i don't know how to use javascript.. will this code automatically post at the td the data from my database when i open this php code in my browser? what i want to is, when i open it in browser it will load data.. and when i drop down the option in my select and choose one, it will also change the value or the text of the textbox which is also from my database. for ex. is if i choose 12abc from select option as productcode from my code field, my textbox will also  change the text which is from my productname field in my datatable

Comment: I have edited my comment can you please try that code

Comment: itried your codes the first time open it, the textbox does not showing . but when i dropdown the select options and choose one, the textbox will show empty which is not what suppose to be.. i mean it should have text from my database. the other thing is, your code can't change the value.

Comment: forgot to put value in option please add value in option tag value=".$data['prodcode']." edited the comment please check

Comment: got it!! the problem is, the select options does not change even i clicked it.. when i open it in browser, the select has the text which is from my database but when i drop it down and choose one option it's text does not change.. the textbox is the only one changing the text. why?

Comment: check is submtted choice and value from database are equal before adding to select box .. code edited please check

Comment: yes the same, all choices from select options are there and those are from my database table. still there is a problem.. when i click some choice the text will just flash and then go back to the first choice.. thats doesn't change.. whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this?

```
<?PHP
echo '
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="query">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
';
if($_POST["query"]){
 $variable = $_POST["query"];
 echo $variable;
}echo '
</body>
</html>';
?>
```

Comment: i tried this code but it is not working it doesn't echoing the variable. always showing the error: Notice: Undefined index: query in C:\xampp\htdocs\se\index.php